# iOS UINavigationBar button remains faded after segue back

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, ios11.2

In my app I have multiple view controllers, and most have a right-hand-side `UIBarButtonItem` with direct "show" segue actions attached.

Having segued to another view and then pressed the `'< Back'` button, the original button item remains faded out, although still otherwise usable.

This only appears to happen under iOS 11.2.

I can't see any setting that could be doing this, and in at least one of the cases where this happens there's no specific segue unwinding nor `viewDidAppear` handling.  I'd post some code, but AFAICS it's all just default `UINavigationBar` behaviour.

Comment: Hope you filed a radar on this awful, awful bug.

Comment: Looks like this is resolved in iOS 11.3

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is a bug in iOS 11.2 and happens because the `UIBarButtonItem` stays highlighted after navigation and does not return to its normal state after the other view controller pops.

To avoid this behavior, either

1. use a `UIBarButtonItem` with a `UIButton` as a custom view
2. disable and re-enable the bar button item in `viewWillDisappear(_:)` (although this causes the button to appear immediately, use [matt's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47839657/3151675) to avoid this):

   ```
   barButtonItem.isEnabled = false
   barButtonItem.isEnabled = true
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Might it also be possible to reset the button's state in the `viewDidAppear()` method?

Comment: @Alnitak I added a second option to my answer which addresses the issue in a different way.

Comment: thanks - either seems to work, I'm unsure which I find more visually appealing.   If I do it in `viewWillDisappear(_:)` then the button is immediately visible when the view pops.  If I do it in `viewDidAppear(_:)` then it animates back into visibility.

Comment: p.s. if you know of any links to other reports of this behaviour that would be very useful

Comment: You can also flip the enabled state in `viewDidDisappear` instead of `viewWillDisappear`. No visual artifacts.

Comment: Strange. Neither solution working on my side when doing pop navigation with custom interactive animator :0

Comment: I ended up with UIBarButtonItem with custom view (UIButton) inside.

Answer (score 24):

What I do is work around this bug, in the view controller's `viewWillAppear`, as follows:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintAdjustmentMode = .normal
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintAdjustmentMode = .automatic
}
```

That seems to wake up the button without visual artifacts.

Comment: It's not working when user swiped back using edge gesture. Tried viewDidAppear and it works but then when we go back using button it has a small delay for view to appear. Any thoughts how we can improve this?

Comment: Thanks! This works for me. Both for clicking the back button and swiping.

Answer (score 5):

Another work around is to implement the fix on the parent navigationController - so that each of its child viewController's gets the fix as follows

NOTE: This requires the receiving class to be setup as the UINavigationController delegate

**Swift**

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    if #available(iOS 11.2, *) {
        navigationBar.tintAdjustmentMode = .normal
        navigationBar.tintAdjustmentMode = .automatic
    }
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {    
    if (@available(iOS 11.2, *)) {
        self.navigationBar.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal;
        self.navigationBar.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeAutomatic;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but I cannot get this (or any other workaround) to work when I'm using `popViewController(_)` to go back to the view in question. Is anyone experiencing the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it like this:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintAdjustmentMode = .normal
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintAdjustmentMode = .automatic
}
```

so it will restore the color before the other view appear