# UIPickerView BarButton Text Color is not change but when click on button then the color is change in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uibarbuttonitem

I have issue I have set `UIPickerView` `BarButton` title color to blue but it not give the perfect output but when I click on that button it gives the output means it change the color to blue but I don't want blue color only after click, I want button color blue before click. so how can I do this?

[image]

Code:

```
-(void)SetToolbar
{
    //******* add buttons in toolbar
    self.toolbar=[[UIToolbar alloc]init];
    self.toolbar.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin );
    self.toolbar.frame=CGRectMake(0, self.currencypicker.frame.origin.y, self.currencypicker.frame.size.width, 45);
    self.toolbar.barStyle=UIBarStyleDefault;
    self.toolbar.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    self.toolbar.tintColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    UIBarButtonItem *donebutton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(Btn_DoneClick)];
    //    donebutton.style=UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelbutton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(Btn_CancelClick)];
    UIBarButtonItem *flex = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    UIView *titleview=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 40)];
    titleview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    UILabel *lbltitle=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 40)];
    lbltitle.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    lbltitle.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    lbltitle.text=@"Payment Type";
    lbltitle.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
    if(IS_IPAD)
    {
        lbltitle.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:113.0/256 green:120.0/256 blue:128.0/256 alpha:1.0];
    }
    else
    {
         lbltitle.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    }
    [titleview addSubview:lbltitle];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnAdd=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addPaymentClicked)];

    UIBarButtonItem *titlebutton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:titleview];

    NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cancelbutton,flex,titlebutton,flex,btnAdd, donebutton, nil];
    [self.toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:self.toolbar];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.pickerView];
    //*******
}
```

My Delegate DidFinishCode For Navigation:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:FooterBGColor];
 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
 if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
      [[UINavigationBar appearance] setLargeTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];
      [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];
 } else {

 }
```

Comment: i have tried your code and its displaying "Done" button correctly. something must be breaking from other code.

Comment: I have written some code in AppDelegate i'm just updating  code here please check once that I don't know why this thing is happening !

Comment: i have tried appdelegate code also, this is also working fine. must be breaking from other code.

Comment: can you please tell me which type of properties or something that effect here because I have create all this properties here and I don't change colour any of my code !!

Comment: have you tried commenting appdelegate code once?

Comment: Yes but no effect @Dhaval

Comment: Your code looks great and its working fine, the problem is some where else in the code

Comment: in this project lot's of code there can you please tell me which type of code is change this thing so I can change in my files thank you

Comment: Not sure, could you please try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47754627/2323806 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/47839657/2323806

Comment: Hello @Vinaykrishnan, I check this i follow all answer but still not working !!
Change Button to enable/disable And Set navigationController tintAdjustmode normal/automatic no effect !! what should I do now .?

Comment: Hello Using Navigation code it's working now I forget to do delegate self now it's work Thank You So much @Vinaykrishnan Awesome Brother

Comment: Great:) Happy Coding !

Comment: Yes Thank You once again :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question was asked 10 months ago. But today I still had this issue. I tried changing tint color and I have no idea why it is not working. After spending hours, I finally decided to create a UIView on UIToolbar and then add a UIButton on it. It worked for me. I hope it might help someone in future.

```
// UIPickerView
self.myPickerView = UIPickerView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 216))
self.myPickerView.delegate = self
self.myPickerView.dataSource = self
self.myPickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
cell.myTextField.inputView = self.myPickerView

// ToolBar
let toolBar = UIToolbar()
toolBar.barStyle = .default
toolBar.isTranslucent = true
toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 92/255, green: 216/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
toolBar.sizeToFit()

// UIView
let myNewView=UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 44))
myNewView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
toolBar.addSubview(myNewView)

// UIButton
let button:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: myNewView.bounds.width - 80, y: 0, width: 70, height: 44))
button.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.doneClick), for: .touchUpInside)
myNewView.addSubview(button)

cell.myTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

Answer (score 0):

use tint Color in Donebutton
try This.

```
 UIBarButtonItem *donebutton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(Btn_DoneClick)];
    //    donebutton.style=UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
donebutton.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Comment: let tool = UIToolbar();tool.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
tool.isTranslucent = true
tool.tintColor = UIColor.blue
tool.sizeToFit()
tool.barTintColor = UIColor.blue
tool.backgroundColor = UIColor.white // this is swift code i hope you convert in objective c.

Comment: I try this code still is not working @Pradip i think we missed something !!