# Bar Button doesn't return to default color

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Here is a my simple test project:

A `RootViewController` is embedded in a `NavigationController`. A Bar Button titled "SegueButton" is added to the Nav Bar and set its action to trigger a segue to `ViewController`.
(see the app setup below)

[image: the storyboard]

[image: bar button attributes]

[image: bar button connections]

When I run the app, tapping "SegueButton" enables `ViewController` to show. But when I back to the `RootViewController` by tapping the back button in the upper left corner, the "SegueButton" is showing like it being pressed down.

(see the running screenshots below)

[image: root view]

[image: segue to blank view by tapping SegueButton]

[image: returned to root view with a highlighted SegueButton]

How can I make the "SegueButton" return to its default color every time when I get back?

Thanks, everyone.

Comment: Did you change any thing by the code?

Comment: I guess this is kind of like [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47542641/why-doesnt-bar-button-change-back-to-blue).

Comment: Thanks guys. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47754627/9148248 this solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bug with UIKit. Try implementing this in your `UIViewController` where the problem occurs:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    guard let bar = navigationController?.navigationBar else { return }
    bar.tintAdjustmentMode = .normal
    bar.tintAdjustmentMode = .automatic
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution is partially working. When I quickly tap the barButton and the back button, the issue still happens. While, using `barButtonItem.isEnabled = false` and `barButtonItem.isEnabled = true` in `viewWillAppear` works perfectly.